# Как лучше реализовать новости?

Tags: php, seo

Здравствуйте,как лучше реализовать новости:

- при добавлении новой новости,текст идет в бд,затем на странице со списком новостей,есть кнопка "читать далее" ,при нажатии на нее передается параметр на другую страницу и на этой странице на основе полученного параметра формируется запрос и выводится вся новость
- при добавлении новой новости создается новая страница на сервере с новость и при нажатии "читать далее" просто происходит переход на сгенерированную страницу

Подскажите как лучше быть?Какой метод лучше,просто еще вопрос в SEO 1 метод не очень оптимален.Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Однозначно в БД.
А когда вы захотите ее поменять (новость)?
А когда вы для страницы добавите ключевые слова?
А когда мало ли еще что нужно будет добавить...

Как раз для целей SEO метод 1 более гибкий!

Comment: Но по факту этой страницы нету на сервере,ключевые слова будут в бд же ж находится как поисковая машина найдет?

Comment: @zkolya объясните что такое поисковая машина? Если вы про поискового бота, то он не у вас по серверу лазить будет, а по урлам все запрашивать у вашего сервера.

Или вы такой добрый и дадите всем доступ к своему серверу?)

Comment: Поисковая машина при поиске опирается на meta теги,и проходит по страницам на сайте,а если новость будет храниться в бд и будет подгружаться ее не найдут.

Comment: @zkolya вы не правы...

Comment: Возможно,а как тогда происходит этот процесс и как мне правильнее поступить?

Comment: У каждого поискового бота свои особенности, но не какая приличная компания не попросит вас давать доступ к вашему сайту. Все страницы запрашиваются по url, url правила у вас в .htaccess. Поисковому боту не важно что по этому адрессу, ему важно, что он получет в ответ от сервиса, а ваш php скрипт сгенерит ему страничку не чем не отличающуюся от html страницы...
Я не знаю как еще объяснить...

Comment: Все понял,спасибо за разъяснение.